# SpringMVC : No mapping found for HTTP request

Tags: java, spring-mvc, config

Please have a look at the first line and last line logged in my console.
first line declares that ***/SpringMVC/welcome*** is mapped on to **helloController** but the last line in the log shows otherwise!

**Background**: I have taken the source straight from [MyKong](http://www.mkyong.com/) and tried to run. I haven't changed any configurations, except for changing @RequestMapping("/welcome") to @RequestMapping("/SpringMVC/welcome"). Full source available [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/)

```
INFO: Mapped URL path [/SpringMVC/welcome] onto handler 'helloController'
Jul 2, 2014 8:17:54 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/SpringMVC/welcome.*] onto handler 'helloController'
Jul 2, 2014 8:17:54 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/SpringMVC/welcome/] onto handler 'helloController'
Jul 2, 2014 8:17:54 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization completed in 231 ms
Jul 2, 2014 8:17:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 2, 2014 8:17:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 2, 2014 8:17:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2249 ms
Jul 2, 2014 8:17:55 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
Jul 2, 2014 8:18:03 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

Controller Code:

```
package com.mkyong.common.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/SpringMVC/welcome")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
        return "hello";

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. Your controller method is mapped to

```
/SpringMVC/welcome
```

relative to your context path.

That is, if your context path is

```
/SpringMVC
```

, then the request needs to be sent to

```
/SpringMVC/SpringMVC/welcome
```

Comment: So you changed the original controller code from mykong, from @RequestMapping("/welcome") to @RequestMapping("/SpringMVC/welcome")...